# python x**(p/q) unexpected behavior

Tags: python, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

`x**(p/q)` produces `(x**p)/q` is this a bug, or is this intentional behavior?

I have searched this site and elsewhere on the internet, but cannot find any discussion of this.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Could you provide a specific example of this?

Comment: No it does not: ``2**(4/2)`` --> 4, ``(2**4)/2`` --> 8.

Comment: In python2 division of integers return integer division.

Answer (score 2):

No it doesn't:

```
>>> 2**(20/2)
1024
>>> (2**20)/2
524288
>>> 2**20/2
524288
```

Answer (score 0):

No its not True but if you dont have parenthesis, because of that `/` have lowest precedence (least binding) than Exponentiation (`**`) what you say would be happen !
also in python's wiki :

> The power operator ** binds less tightly than an arithmetic or bitwise unary operator on its right, that is, 2**-1 is 0.5.